# How do i play audio one after another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This program plays a sound based on a number. I have multiple audio files which are very short .wav's. as the question says, I want it to play all sounds in sequence

Comment: Do you have some code for us, examples of things you tried or of a setup?

Answer (score 0):

For playing soundfiles, you could take a look at the following sound libraries:

- [P5 Sound library](https://p5js.org/reference/#/libraries/p5.sound)
- [Tone.js](https://tonejs.github.io/)
- [SoundJS](https://www.createjs.com/soundjs) from CreateJS

If you give me some things you tried yourself, I can help you in case there are problems. But these libraries have good documentation, so you should at least code something yourself we can help you with.